# IF inside sql UPDATE query instead of case

Tags: php, mysql, sql

How should I make a sql update query only IF a value of the table is equal to "something"?
I would not want to use case because I don't have any "else" statement and it is regulated by another simple value of the table, so there are no more cases.

EDIT: Since there is so much need to see one single line of code because certainly my question has no answer this way, I'll leave it here:

```
$query = "IF seen=1 UPDATE something SET other_thing = 100 WHERE yet_another_thing= 'outro' ";
```

Comment: Have you tried anything; any code to go along with this? As much as I love "Pandora's BOX", I don't like "worms", as in "a can of". `$of="worms";`

Comment: [RTFM on `UPDATE`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/update.html) --- The `F` stands for `Fabulous`

Comment: `Your Edit`: You call that code? Come on, Mama didn't raise no fool.

Comment: @Fred-ii- LOL. Surely its more than enough for you to understand what I want ffs xD

Comment: There is far too much information on the Web for you to come and ask something as trivial as this. I'd of easily given an answer, but questions like these tend to open up a can of worms, and I rather eat `baked beans` myself; and I don't like baked beans ;-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking at everyone's answers, here is the code for YOU.

```
$query = "UPDATE something SET other_thing = 100 WHERE yet_another_thing= 'outro' AND seen = 1";
```

Comment: it was so basic all this time, I didn't know "AND" would apply to any sql command (update, set, where, etc). Thank you so much Eisa :)

Answer (score 2):

You use a `where` statement:

```
update t
    set foo = bar
    where value = 'something';
```

Answer (score 1):

This is where use use a `WHERE` clause:

```
UPDATE
    SomeTable
SET
    field = 1234
WHERE
    anotherField = 5678
```

Answer (score 0):

```
UPDATE tablename SET updatevalue = 'value' WHERE avalue = 'something'
```